# Method Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar::groub does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

**`dashboard/web.php`**

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->name('dashboard.')->groub(function(){

    Route::get('/check' , function(){
        return 'This is test Route';
    });

});
```

**RouterServesProvider** file

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
    protected $dashboard_namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\dashboard';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapDashboardRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    protected function mapDashboardRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->dashboard_namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/dashboard/web.php'));
    }
    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This ```->groub``` should be ```->group```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your routes definition:

This one

```php
Route::prefix('dashboard')->name('dashboard.')->groub(function(){
    Route::get('/check' , function(){
        return 'This is test Route';
    });
});
```

Should be `group`, not `groub`:

```php
Route::prefix('dashboard')->name('dashboard.')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/check' , function(){
        return 'This is test Route';
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.